# Streaming download with ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I wrote this code to download a file with Ktor:

```
val resp = httpClient.request {
    url("http://example.com/large_file.dat")
}
resp.bodyAsChannel().copyAndClose(File(cacheDir, "test.foo").writeChannel())
```

When I run it, nothing happens for about 10 seconds, then the file is written rather quickly. This tells me that the file is downloaded to memory and only afterwards written to the file.

How can I make it happen in parallel?

I tried with the *Android* and with the *OkHttp* engine.

Comment: The problem, as you have identified, as the entire byte stream is read into memory and then written to disk. If you try doing this with a large file you'll end up hitting a `OutOfMemoryError`. You should use `HttpClient::prepareGet` which will perform a streaming download.  Example from the ktor client documentation : https://ktor.io/docs/response.html#streaming Here is a small example coupled with `WorkManager` updating progress : https://github.com/TreeFrogApps/ktor-test/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/treefrogapps/ktor/test/download/workers/ChunkedDownloadListenableWorker.kt

Comment: @Mark Thanks, using `prepareRequest {}` and `execute {}` instead of `request {}` solved the issue. In other HTTP clients I know streaming is usually the default and `body()` does the download.

Answer (score 2):

Following Mark's comment, I changed the code to:

```kotlin
httpClient.prepareRequest {
    url("http://example.com/large_file.dat")
}.execute { resp ->
    resp.bodyAsChannel().copyAndClose(File(cacheDir, "test.foo").writeChannel())
}
```

Now the data is streamed as expected.